# Creating a To-Do list with Jquery, can't delete dynamically added Table Rows by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have code that takes the input from a text box and adds it to the to do lsit body which is a table element. Each input added creates a new tr that has the value entered into the box and appears with an inline button beside it.

Before I added the buttons, my on click function to remove the TR worked. Now that I am trying to use the buttons to delete the tr on click, it either does nothing or deletes the button but keeps the tr and it's text.

```
 $('input').keypress(function(event){
    var x = $('input:first').val();
    if(event.which === 13){
        $('#listTable').append('<tr class= "listItem"><td><button type="button"  class="btn btn-default deleteButton" aria-label="Left Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>'+x+'</td></tr>')//adds a new tr with the input from the box and prints it in the td of the tr
        $('input').val("");
    }
    $('.deleteButton').on('click', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#listTable').on('click', '.deleteButton' , function(){
    alert('remove');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    //or $(this).closest('.listItem').remove();
});
```

Instead of

```
$('.deleteButton').on('click', function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I just have 2 questions which you don't have to answer.
1. the .deletebutton in the middle of the on click function why is that there?

Comment: Great! Because you added dynamical content, then you need a scope to bind click event.

Comment: I don't quite understand but im going to search into that before i continue finishing my project. I appreciate all your help I was stuck on that for a while

Comment: Please, check: http://api.jquery.com/on/  "Direct and delegated events"

Comment: I'd go with `$(this).closest('.listItem').remove();` this should be more robust, in case the markup for the rows should ever change.